# Use generic type parameter in Yup schema

Tags: typescript, yup

With Yup, I don't see how to do this... (nonsense code)

```
const MySchema = y.object({
  prop1: y.generic("T")
});

type MyType = y.InferType<typeof MySchema> // type MyType<T> = { prop1: T }

MySchema.validate({ prop1: "Hello" }, { T: y.string() });
```

So the schema has a generic type parameter, which is set when `validate` is called.

Is this possible with the existing API?